# Unable to copy using wl-copy (wl-clipboard) - issue with `xdg-mime`

Tags: arch-linux, files, clipboard, xdg

- OS: Arch linux (linux-6.8.1.arch1-1)
- WM: Hyprland

When I run `echo 'hello' | wl-copy`, I get the following output:

```bash
echo "hello" | wl-copy
Usage: file [-bcCdEhikLlNnprsSvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding]
            [--mime-type] [-e <testname>] [-F <separator>]  [-f <namefile>]
            [-m <magicfiles>] [-P <parameter=value>] [--exclude-quiet]
            <file> ...
       file -C [-m <magicfiles>]
       file [--help]
```

However, I'm able to copy text with `wl-copy Hello World`

The interesting part is that wl-clipboard does not have `file` as it's dependency, it instead uses xdg-mime. When I try and run `xdg-mime query filetype <file>`, for every file I get the same error as above

```bash
xdg-mime query filetype ./.bash_history
Usage: file [-bcCdEhikLlNnprsSvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding]
            [--mime-type] [-e <testname>] [-F <separator>]  [-f <namefile>]
            [-m <magicfiles>] [-P <parameter=value>] [--exclude-quiet]
            <file> ...
       file -C [-m <magicfiles>]
       file [--help]
```

I don't understand why calling xdg-mime would show me usage of `file`.
How can I debug this further. Is it a package conflict or a version conflict or a broken installation?

EDIT:
Searching about it a little I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317193/linux-shell-cli-file-get-mime-type-from-a-string-variable), and that led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045479/whats-the-magic-of-a-dash-in-command-line-parameters). This could probably be a version incompatibility issue?

Comment: xdg-mime is a shell-script in /usr/bin/xdg-mime, xdg-mime query filetype is passing the arguments "query" and "filetype" to the script, which calls the info_generic function inside. if the command "mimetype" is not found, this function calls the file command "/usr/bin/file"  it seems that on your side the file command is called with wrong arguments, can you post the "info_generic" function inside your xdg-mime script in "/usr/bin".

Comment: i show you my function ```info_generic()
{
    if mimetype --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        DEBUG 1 "Running mimetype --brief --dereference \"$1\""
        mimetype --brief --dereference "$1"
    else
        DEBUG 1 "Running file --brief --dereference --mime-type \"$1\""
        /usr/bin/file --brief --dereference --mime-type "$1" 2> /dev/null
    fi

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        exit_success
    else
        exit_failure_operation_failed
    fi
}```

Comment: ```sh
info_generic()
{
    if mimetype --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        DEBUG 1 "Running mimetype --brief --dereference \"$1\""
        mimetype --brief --dereference "$1"
    else
        DEBUG 1 "Running file --brief --dereference --mime-type \"$1\""
        /usr/bin/file --brief --dereference --mime-type "$1" 2> /dev/null
    fi

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        exit_success
    else
        exit_failure_operation_failed
    fi
}
```
@Schmaehgrunza

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza Your comment is basically the answer to my query. I found an orphan `mimetype` shell script in the path. I'm not sure how it got there, as this is a fresh installation, but removing it fixed my issue. Thank you. I could mark that as the answer if you would post it as one.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit where you tagged the question title with "SOLVED".  A question is marked as solved if you accept an answer (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).  If a _comment_ helped you to solve your issue, you may create an answer using the comment as a basis, unless somebody else does that before you (the author of the comment, for example). It's perfectly ok to answer your own question in this manner (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @chaitanya sharma orphan mimetype script and that script did call the file command with wrong parameters? I dont post an answer, because i didnt know, what caused the problem, it was just a hint, let this question open, if they dont accept, that you marked it as answered.

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza The orphan mimetype script did not use file command at all, it had it's own limited checking. Removing this file fixed the issue because then the actual mimetype program was being called by wl-copy.

Comment: @chaitanya sharma mysterious, because the standard error of the file command in your info_generic function is also linked to /dev/null. It's magic, perhaps santa claus called the file command and then this error shows up.